# Function is not returning true or false, if it is correct

Tags: php, json

I am writing a function which checks nested keys if it exists in JSON, but i hav stuck at place when if code is correct then it must return true or false but it is not. it returns null value

php function is

```
function checkNestedKeysExists($JSONRequest,$keyCheckArray){
$currentKey = current($keyCheckArray);
$JSONRequest = array_change_key_case($JSONRequest, CASE_LOWER); 

    if(array_key_exists($currentKey,$JSONRequest)){
        if($currentKey==end($keyCheckArray)){
            return true;            
        }    
        else { 
            array_shift($keyCheckArray);  
            $this->checkNestedKeysExists($JSONRequest[$currentKey],$keyCheckArray);                
            //echo "F";
        }    
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

given array is

```
$keyCheckArray = array('data','device_info','deviceid');
```

and $JSONRequest is

```
{
"timestamp": "2014-01-01 11:11:11",
"data": {
    "requestid": "bcpcvssi1",
    "device_info": {
        "os": "Android",
        "deviceId": "123123",
        "userProfile": {
            "email": [
                "abc@gmail.com"
            ],
            "gender": "Male",
            "age": "19",
            "interest": [
                "Apple",
                "Banana"
            ]
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You need to return the output of the recursive function. `return $this->checkNestedKeysExists($JSONRequest[$currentKey],$keyCheckArray);`.

Comment: that is the first advice I gave to you in my answer.

Comment: @LoekBergman OP most likely didn't realize his flaw, so "*give the function with every possible way to end the function a valid return value.*" might not be useful to someone who's getting into the language. If it was so obvious OP would've probably done it himself. :-)

Comment: @h2ooooooo: that makes sense, I have heard it before that I talk sometimes too abstract. Well, I hope that the OP will still take the advice with him. If I would have done that from the onset of my programming,then would I have had less problems to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the line of your code where you make recursive call like following

```
return $this->checkNestedKeysExists($JSONRequest[$currentKey],$keyCheckArray);
```

So it will return the result of the call

Answer (score 0):

pass $JSONRequest in

```
json_decode($JSONRequest, true);
```

Comment: He is using array functions. Maybe you have to mentioned the second parameter to create an array ;)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Sorry I got it wrong in first time.
Use `array[0]` instead of `current()` if you are shifting elements, maybe it is making a problem. And of course, do the `var_dump()` to check values.

Answer (score 0):

$currentkey = 'data' and end($keyCheckArray) = 'deviceid'. That will never return true, hence you have no return values specified and it will return null.

two advices:

1. give the function with every possible way to end the function a valid return value.
2. create a variable for every fixed outcome like end($keyCheckArray).

If have tested your function (and edited it for testing purposes):

```
function checkNestedKeysExists($JSONRequest,$keyCheckArray){
  $currentKey = current($keyCheckArray);
  $JSONRequest = array_change_key_case($JSONRequest, CASE_LOWER); 
  $endValue = end($keyCheckArray);

if(array_key_exists($currentKey,$JSONRequest)){
    print 'currentKey = '.$currentKey.", end = ".$endValue."<br>\n";
    if($currentKey== $endValue){
        return 'correct';            
    }else { 
        array_shift($keyCheckArray);  
        $p = checkNestedKeysExists($JSONRequest[$currentKey],$keyCheckArray);
        print "p = ".$p."<br>\n";
        //echo "F";
        return $currentKey;
    }    
}
else{
    return false;
}
}
```

The output is like this:
correct

device_info

data

I suggest you change your function into a while loop. Once you have found the requested result, return true.

Comment: dry run the code, due to recursion it reach the point where $currentkey = 'deviceid' and end($keyCheckArray) = 'deviceid'. And it has a valid return function, and end($keyCheckArray) is always fixed

Comment: to create a variable for a fixed outcome is making use of the flyweight design pattern and is memory usage friendly.

Comment: when I run your code I get the message that $this-> etc. is not possible without an object reference. This function is a method within an object. Your $JSONRequest is an array, hence there has been some work done on it, before you let it enter the function. It is therefor not the same as what you give us as $JSONRequest. That will make it too hard to research.